# Unknown error -1 when trying to mount an .img file

Tags: server, mount

I'm in a folder where is the `system.img`.
I want to mount it in a subfolder named `system`

I'm doing this command on ubuntu 15.04 server, that is proven working on Linux Mint 17.3

```
sudo mount -t ext4 -o loop system.img system/
```

But I got this error on my Ubuntu sever:

> mount: system/: mount failed: Unknown error -1

I'm not able to diagnose what could be the problem.

For your info :

```
sudo fdisk -lu system.img
Disk system.img: 1.9 GiB, 2013143040 bytes, 3931920 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Already tried using `-t auto`

```
sudo mount -t auto -o loop system.img system/
mount: system/: mount failed: Unknown error -1
```

Dmsg after mount tempt is empty:

```
# sudo mount -t ext4 -o loop system.img system/
mount: system/: mount failed: Unknown error -1
# sudo dmesg | tail
#
```

Free space is enough:

```
df -H
Filesystem         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/ploop23074p1   11G  6.9G  3.1G  70% /
```

Before you ask:

- the `.img` file is ok [checked file sha1]
- the same img file can be mounted on the Mint distro
- the `system` subfolder doesn't exists

Comment: What does `sudo fdisk -lu system.img` show? And perhaps try `-t auto` in your `mount` command...

Comment: I updated original post with info you requested me.

Comment: Output of `dmesg | tail` immediately after a mount attempt?

Comment: @fkraiem: it's empty

Comment: That's not normal, maybe try with `sudo dmesg` instead.

Comment: @fkraiem: empty again, even with `sudo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I tried with a machine with more RAM and I got no more problems.

So definetively, 512 MB of RAM for Ubuntu 15.04 is too less for my purposes.